# Coordinator layout and showing a text when toolbar colapses

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to use `CoordinatorLayout` for the first time. From reading the docs and searching for tutorials, I didn't really understand anything about it.
I tried playing around with the code.  So what I need is something like the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:title="@string/the_title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/london_flat"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/flexible.example.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

which I got from a tutorial and when scrolling up as the image moves out and the toolbar starts to get opaque the `app:title="@string/the_title"` is used to be moved up and be the actual text in the app bar once the image has moved out.
How can I modify this so that there is no text in `app:title` and as we scroll up either I set the actual text once the action bar becomes opaque or I use another `TextView` to move its copy there?